# Apress Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework Chapter 7 - 9 - getting downloaded SportsStore project to build with Moq

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Struggling to get the SportsStore project to build. Just downloaded it - changed nothing - just want to make it work first and then go through it step by step.

The first error is that the namespace 'Moq' could not be found in the Test modules with the using statement : using Mock;

All the following modules are using Mock.

AdminControllerTest.cs

ProductControllerTest.cs

AccountControllerTest.cs

NavControllerTest.cs

CartControllerTest.cs

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) and add a reference to it.
You can also reference it using NuGet.

Comment: I did install Nuget as per the book and even verifying the moq commands in the Console Package Manager - it is installed well. I get the following error:     Warning 6 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Moq". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. SportsStore.UnitTests

Comment: The rest of the project works perfectly - just cannot get the testing going with moq .. any advice will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, the easy way to download and install it is to use NuGet. Right click your project, click Manage NuGet Packages, search for Moq, and click the install button. Then the references and everything are handled for you.

More info if you haven't used NuGet before: http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started

Comment: I did install Nuget as per the book and even verifying the moq commands in the Console Package Manager - it is installed well. I get the following error:     Warning 6 Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Moq". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. SportsStore.UnitTests